# Setting 'h1' title on the Contact form in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, contact-us

I am trying to set a page title which is different to the `<h1>` heading for my contact page, but there is [a bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5231) which does not let you use XML on the contact form, so I have included it in the `<head>` tags.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Contact Us - Test</title>
    <link rel="canonical" src="http://www.extenderstore.com.au/contact/" src_type="url"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-store-info" after="contactForm">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">contact_us</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />
</body>
```

How can I have a page title of "Contact Us - Test" and an `<h1>` heading of "Contact Us"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below code for h1 tag

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Reach to Us</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Open your `contacts_index_index.xml` file inside your layout folder and place this code above the body tag.

```
<head>
    <title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
```

If above code does not work for you then do following.

This is a function under `vendor/magento/module-contact/Block/ContactForm.php`

It contains the following code:

```
/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Contact Form'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to translation file {your_theme}/i18n/en_US.csv of Your theme string

"Contact Us","Contact Us - Test"